# Could'nt install (-113) while installing apk in xiaomi devices

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk, xiaomi, redmi-device

[image: Getting this error while installing all in xiaomi devices]

Hi, I am trying install my debug apk in xiaomi device but apk is not installing, it's throwing error code -113 refer attached screenshot, can anyone help to come out from this issue

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable MIUI optimization, you can find it on Settings > Additional Settings > Developer Options and after that it will automatically restart your phone if it's not do it manually.